# How to iterate through a collection in a Meteor template and display only three items per row?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

My Meteor application uses the Skeleton framework. On one page, it will display a list of documents from a MongoDB database in a `div` table. Right now, I have the following code in my template.

```
<div class="row">
    {{#each plans}}
    <div class="four columns plan">
        <h3>{{plan_name}}</h3>
        <p>{{description}}</p>
        <div class="price">{{price}} for {{days}} days</div>
        <a class="button button-primary buy-plan" id="{{_id}}" rel="{{plan_name}}">Buy Now</a>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

But the code above is putting everything in one row, and I am having trouble figuring out how I can get it to reproduce the HTML below where there are only three items per row. How can I achieve this result?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="four columns plan">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="four columns plan">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="four columns plan">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="four columns plan">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="four columns plan">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="four columns plan">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do precisely what you want, but you could add some bootstrap 1/3 width columns. I wonder if from the div class if this wasn't where you were headed:

```
<div class="row">
    {{#each plans}}
      <div class="four_columns_plan col-xs-4">
        <h3>{{plan_name}}</h3>
        <p>{{description}}</p>
        <div class="price">{{price}} for {{days}} days</div>
        <a class="button button-primary buy-plan" id="{{_id}}" rel="{{plan_name}}">Buy Now</a>
      </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

This will basically give you one big row with a bunch of stacked 1/3 width columns.